# Calculating the average ("hitrate") of football results

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, statistics

I want to find the average (or the "hit rate") of World Cup football results. I have calculated 2 points for correct 1X2, and 3 points for correct 1X2 + correct score. So the hit rate should be "yes" or "1" for 2 and 3 points and "no" or "0" for 0 points. I tried using the `AVERAGEIFS()` function, but got a `#DIV/0!` error.

So, the result should be a percentage of the correct outcomes of the total games played, but not including the games not yet played in the average.

In this case (after 10 games) the hit rate is 70%. I need the hit rate calculated after the matches are played. If I put "/10" I only get the first 10 matches. I need a formula where I calculate the average for the matches played (only the cells with "Home", "Draw", and "Away", excluding "Not played") which automatically includes the played matches as they are played. (When `A13:A49` = Home/Draw/Away, it will be included in the average hit-rate)

Probably not a difficult question, but I'd really appreciate the solution!
Image of excel-sheet:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Your question needs some more work, it's not easy to understand.

[image: Final]

**Create a new column for your hitrate for Yes or No**

2 or 3 Points = Yes

0 Points = No

```
=IF(A2="not played","", IF(B2>=2, "Yes", "No"))
```

**Use `COUNTIFS` to get the total number of games played.**

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A13:A49,{"home","away","draw"}))
```

**Average**

Average = # of Yes / Total Games Played

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(C2:C30,"yes"))/SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A30,{"home","away","draw"}))
```

[image: Formulas]